# How can I heal fast in a dungeon in ADOM?

Tags: adom

Since I can't rest or sleep in a dungeon in ADOM like I can in DCSS or Diggr, what are my options when I am low on health in a dungeon and with no items or spells to heal me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't remember any method of healing *quickly*, but I do remember healing slowly with time.  Which could be sped up a bit by walking around and searching.

From [the FAQ](http://www.adomgb.info/adomfaq.html#2.6):
2.6: Is there a command that allows you to rest safely in order to regain hit points and power points?

Yes, actually you can use the walk-mode to do this. Simply press 'w' to activate the walk-mode followed by '5' for the direction which makes your character 'walk on the spot' and is great for safely recovering. You'll automatically stop waiting if something comes near, if you get shot at, etc.

Comment: The walk mode thing worked - it's what I was looking for. Thanks!